# Unable to inject class with Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am attempting to add Dagger 2 to my Android Project.  I think I understand the concepts up to the point of where I build the graph.  At that point I'm shooting in the dark and that is where I'm going wrong.
Everything compiles, but the injected field is null at Runtime.

I am attempting to start simply by injecting the Presenter into my MainActivity.  I have written the following code and would appreciate some help figuring out where I have gone wrong.

My PresenterModule.java:

```
@Module
public class PresenterModule {

  @Provides MainActivityPresenter providesMainActivityPresenter() {
    return new DefaultMainActivityPresenter();
  }
}
```

My Application class which also includes my Component following the Dagger2 example code:

```
public class App extends Application {

  private PresenterComponent component;

  @Singleton
  @Component(modules = PresenterModule.class)
  public interface PresenterComponent {
    void inject(App app);
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
  }


  @Override public void onCreate() {
    Log.d("App.java", "Starting Application");
    super.onCreate();

    component = DaggerApp_PresenterComponent.builder()
        .presenterModule(new PresenterModule())
        .build();
    component.inject(this);
  }

  public PresenterComponent component() {
    return component;
  }
}
```

And finally my MainActivity.

```
public class DefaultMainActivity
    extends ActionBarActivity
    implements MainActivity
{
  @Inject MainActivityPresenter mPresenter;

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ((App)getApplication()).component().inject(this);

    mPresenter.getCurrentDetailLineNumber();
    setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);

    getSupportActionBar();

    mContainer = (Container) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mPresenter.requestCurrentScreen();
  }
```

The actual object to be injected is an implementation of an interface but is other wise a POJO object:

```
public class DefaultMainActivityPresenter implements MainActivityPresenter {

  private static final int SCREEN_BROWSER = 0;
  private static final int SCREEN_DETAIL = 1;

  LineNumber mCurrentDetailLineNumber;
  int mCurrentScreen;

  @Inject
  public DefaultMainActivityPresenter() {
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: you don't say what the error is, compile time typing? null pointer? ...

Comment: Sorry, the injected variable is null at runtime. Everything compiles fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing PresenterComponent to following will fix your problem:

```
  @Singleton
  @Component(modules = PresenterModule.class)
  public interface PresenterComponent {
    void inject(App app);
    void inject(DefaultMainActivity activity);
  }
```

This is due to covariance:
While a members-injection method for a type will accept instances of its subtypes, only Inject-annotated members of the parameter type and its supertypes will be injected; members of subtypes will not. For example, given the following types, only a and b will be injected into an instance of Child when it is passed to the members-injection method injectSelf(Self instance):

```
   class Parent {
     @Inject A a;
   }

   class Self extends Parent {
     @Inject B b;
   }

   class Child extends Self {
     @Inject C c;
   }
```

Comment: Does every class that needs an injected variable need an inject() call in the Component?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. However, inject method will initialize all members up the inheritance chain.